# JS: Intl.NumberFormat -> is there a .NET alternative?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, number-formatting, intl

We have a need to mimic **JS Intl.NumberFormat** under .NET (C#) when it gets to formatting currencies.

In one part of the system we have calls like the following:

```
Intl.NumberFormat('fr-CM', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD', trailingZeroDisplay: "stripIfInteger" }).format(1234,09)
```

Which yields: `1 234,09 $CA` in a browser.

Under .NET C# for CultureInfo "fr-CM" when NumberFormat property is replaced with the one from CultureInfo "en-CA" it gives: `$1,234.09`

Given I couldn't find a built-in way OR a NuGet which mimics the Intl.NumberFormat, I have to ask here.

### Do you fellows know of any NuGet or a built-in way of mimicking JS **Intl.NumberFormat** using .NET?

**Please note:**
Passing data in pieces to the FrontEnd to call `Intl` there is not an option.
Manual NumberFormat mutation is not an option.
Creation of a mapping structure is not an option. All due to LARGE number of `CultureCode * CurrencyCode` cimbinations and we don't want to mess with manual support of such a mapping.

Comment: If you use `ToString("C2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CM"))` you will get "1 234,09 FCFA"? I think you would have to manually override the `NumberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol` to match what you are doing, however (`var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CM").NumberFormat.Clone(); nfi.CurrencySymbol = "$CA"; var ans = 1234.09.ToString("C2", nfi");`

Comment: Yeah. After a research not me nor a teammate could find any legit .NET alternative to the JS Intl.NumberFormat.  
We decided to search for alternatives at the business level.

Comment: You could do this via a function that calls a [Deno](https://deno.land/) subprocess — Deno includes the Intl API and required ICU data

Comment: @jsejcksn Thanks for the piece of advice. Will keep it in mind when time comes to revisit the task. For now we've postponed the change given lower priority.